# ¿Cómo puedo extraer solo la fecha de una cadena de datos en xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Hola tengo el siguiente código que me devuelve una cadena de datos, en formato texto, no consigo extraer el siguiente formato 2021-01-10.

Gracias de antemano.

La consulta que tengo es esta : /incidencias/siniestros/actualizaciones/actualizacion/@fecha/data()

```
 <actualizaciones>
  <actualizacion siniestro="S21000089" fecha="2021-01-01T12:30:00Z" estado="atendido"/>
  <actualizacion siniestro="S21000089" fecha="2021-01-01T13:45:00Z" estado="resuelto">El enchufe está bien. Se recomienda al cliente que no conecte la estufa hasta comprobar cable en servicio técnico.</actualizacion>
  <actualizacion siniestro="S21000153" fecha="2021-01-01T16:30:00Z" estado="alta"/>
  <actualizacion siniestro="S21000168" fecha="2021-01-01T21:15:00Z" estado="alta"/>
</actualizaciones>
```

y el resultado este :

2021-01-01T12:30:00Z  
2021-01-01T13:45:00Z  
2021-01-01T16:30:00Z  
2021-01-01T21:15:00Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede usar una expresión regular:

```
/incidencias/siniestros/actualizaciones/actualizacion/@fecha/replace(., 'T.*', '')
```

Comment: Gracias @Christian Grün voy a probar y comento un saludo !

Comment: Funciona perfecto, ahora la pequeña duda es como formatear el texto y ponerlo en orden mes dia año tocará investigar un poco, gracias !

Comment: Hola @Christian Grün, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), ya que responder solo con código es considerado de baja calidad.

Comment: Hola @ivan hernandez aguilar, ¿qué mejorarías en mi respuesta? Gracias.

Comment: Aunque la respuesta es correcta y funcional, se recomienda que expliques como funciona, ej:
La expresion regular filtra ... mediante ... logrando.